# Why not to allow changing usernames?

Tags: uri, search-engine, record

There are several services which allow change of usernames frequently like `Twitter`, `LinkedIn` etc. Some other have very limited options (example: `Facebook` for two times). And rest does not allow changing usernames.

The major reasons I can understand is, `records` are kept against usernames and the `URL` are cached by search engines against the username. But to solve the first problem, which is much vital, applications can use `userid` instead of `username`.

Is there any other important issues/reasons for which I should consider disallow changing usernames?

Answer (score 2):

the main issue is social engineering.  people associate a reputation with a name (both the user with the name, and the people who interact with them).  if you allow names to change then there is less social pressure to preserve a good reputation and more "bad behaviour".

it's all about coercing users to invest social status in a persistent identity.  technically they could implement a system that supports name changes (for example, you could use an arbitrary, unique, auto-generated ID to represent the user in the database/cache/file system and display some (user modifiable) string from the database when showing the name in a web page).

Answer (score 0):

There are technical reasons behind some sites disallowing namechanges, such as if the users have the ability to store files, changing the username may break it if the file paths are based on the usernames. However, a good implementation uses user IDs instead, and avoids such things. For the most part, its a social matter of keeping a permanent link between a user's name and an account. Giving the user the ability to switch names gives other users the ability to impersonate them, or steal their name, and makes it difficult to find people sometimes.

I'd also like to note that there is a difference between login usernames, and nicknames. What you are calling 'username' is moreso a nickname if it can be changed, and usually sites that let you 'change your username' are only letting you change your display name - your login remains the same. Steam is a good example of this, it allows you to change a nickname, but your login name can never change.

Answer (score -3):

I have recently came across this dilemma whether to allow user to change username.

I have entered it on my blog: http://www.dizkover.com/post/423/programming-why-not-to-allow-users-to-change-username-in-social-web-application-design

Comment: When linking to an external resource, please include a summary of that resource in your answer.

Comment: Be carefull, the first time you click the above link, it takes you to the top-level of the domain, and it appears to be some sort of pintrist-ish site.